# Having trouble publishing my Ruby gem due to NoMethod errors and problems relating to my .gemspec file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, publishing, nomethoderror, gemspecs

I'm receiving this error when executing `gem push pick_a_key-0.1.0.gem`

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not entirely sure why I'm receiving it considering the app works fine when I run it.

I've also tried running `bundle exec rake build`
When this is run, I receive:

```
32: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    31: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    30: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    29: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
    28: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
    27: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    26: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:142:in `setup'
    25: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:194:in `definition'
    24: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:34:in `build'
    23: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
    22: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:232:in `to_definition'
    21: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:232:in `new'
    20: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `initialize'
    19: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:643:in `converge_paths'
    18: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:643:in `any?'
    17: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:644:in `block in converge_paths'
    16: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:600:in `specs_changed?'
    15: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:615:in `specs_for_source_changed?'
    14: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:113:in `specs'
    13: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:105:in `local_specs'
    12: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:174:in `load_spec_files'
    11: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:174:in `each'
    10: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:180:in `block in load_spec_files'
     9: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:166:in `validate_spec'
     8: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:70:in `validate'
     7: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
     6: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
     5: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:70:in `block in validate'
     4: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2588:in `validate'
     3: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:44:in `validate'
     2: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:75:in `validate_required!'
     1: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:306:in `validate_self_inclusion_in_files_list'
/home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:477:in `error': pick_a_key-0.1.0 contains itself (pick_a_key-0.1.0.gem), check your files list (Gem::InvalidSpecificationException)
    25: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    24: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    23: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
    21: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
    20: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    19: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:142:in `setup'
    18: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:194:in `definition'
    17: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:34:in `build'
    16: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:13:in `evaluate'
    15: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:232:in `to_definition'
    14: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/dsl.rb:232:in `new'
    13: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `initialize'
    12: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:643:in `converge_paths'
    11: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:643:in `any?'
    10: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:644:in `block in converge_paths'
     9: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:600:in `specs_changed?'
     8: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:615:in `specs_for_source_changed?'
     7: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:113:in `specs'
     6: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:105:in `local_specs'
     5: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:174:in `load_spec_files'
     4: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:174:in `each'
     3: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:180:in `block in load_spec_files'
     2: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/source/path.rb:166:in `validate_spec'
     1: from /home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:69:in `validate'
/home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:74:in `rescue in validate': The gemspec at /home/taylor/code/pick_a_key/pick_a_key.gemspec is not valid. Please fix this gemspec. (Gem::InvalidSpecificationException)
The validation error was 'pick_a_key-0.1.0 contains itself (pick_a_key-0.1.0.gem), check your files list'
```

Below is my pick_a_key.gemspec file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require_relative "lib/pick_a_key/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "pick_a_key"
  spec.version       = PickAKey::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Taylor Treece"]
  spec.email         = ["xxxxxxxx.com"]

  spec.summary       = "The Pick-a-Key gem allows you to quickly find relevant information on music theory, specifically relating to Major and Minor keys."
  spec.description   = "When started, the gem lists all available Major and minor keys, and then prompts you to make a selection. Once selected, a key object is made a available to the user. The attributes related to the key object are :Type (Major or minor), :Name (e.g. C Major ), :Notes (all notes in the listed key), :Chords (all chords in listed key), :Relative_fifth, :Relative_Major/:Relative_minor. The user also has the option of having a single random chord progression returned to them in a key of their choice, or an entire song written in the key of their choice."
  spec.homepage      = "https://github.com/taylortreece/pick-a-key.git."
  spec.license       = "MIT"
  spec.required_ruby_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">= 2.4.0")

  spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = 'rubygems.org'

  spec.metadata["homepage_uri"] = spec.homepage

  # Specify which files should be added to the gem when it is released.
  # The `git ls-files -z` loads the files in the RubyGem that have been added into git.
  spec.files = Dir.chdir(File.expand_path(__dir__)) do
    `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{\A(?:test|spec|features)/}) }
  end
  #spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = ["pick-a-key"]
  #spec.files.grep(%r{\Aexe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
  spec.add_development_dependency "pry"
  spec.add_dependency "nokogiri"
  spec.add_dependency "prettyprint"

  # Uncomment to register a new dependency of your gem
  # spec.add_dependency "example-gem", "~> 1.0"
```

Any idea on what I should do? I'm positive something is wrong with my gemspec considering the error messages, but I'm just not sure how to go about solving it.

Answer (score 0):

The last lines of the error are the important ones. `pick_a_key-0.1.0.gem` is part of the files that you included in your git repo (got them later in your gemspec file by `git ls-files -z`).
So, remove the file from your repository and that should make the trick.